# How to Get Hidden ID value in Datatables on Modal

Tags: php, jquery, datatables

I have modal to lookup data in datatables that I hid ID row.

At first time I click the modal, I can get the data in datatables and send to textbox.

but the next on it is showed error:

```
TypeError: dtCustomers.row(...).data(...) is undefined
```

my code is like this:

```
function getCustomers(){
  $.ajax({
    type: 'get',
    url: '<?=base_url("customer/generate") ?>',
    data : {},
    dataType: 'json',
    success : function(result){
        var data = [];
        var no = 0;
        for(i=0; i < result.length; i++){
        no = no + 1;                            
        data.push([no,result[i].id,result[i].code,result[i].name,result[i].email,result[i].address,result[i].city,result[i].phone_no,result[i].cellphone_no]);

      }
      var dtCustomers = $('#customerLookup').DataTable( {
            data : data,
            destroy: true,
            'dom': 'Bfrtip',
            'buttons': [{
            text: '<i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add',
            className:'btn btn-sm btn-success',
            titleAttr: 'Add',
            attr:  {
                id: 'btnAddCustomer',
                'data-toggle' : 'modal',
                'data-target' : '#mdlAddCustomer',
            }
          }],
          "columnDefs": [
            {
                "targets": [1],
                "visible": false,
                "searchable": false
            },
        ]});

           dtCustomers.columns.adjust();

           $('#customerLookup tbody').on( 'click', 'tr', function () {
                var id  = dtCustomers.row(this).data()[1];
                var code    = dtCustomers.row(this).data()[2];

                $('#customer_id').val(id);
                $('#customer_code').val(code);

            $("#customerLookupModal").modal('hide');
        });                   
    }
  });
};
```

I want to get hidden row in datatables without error on next I open the modal to look the data.

Comment: can you put your data tables in your question?